# Base map is not showing

Tags: qgis

I want to load an OSM map via de XYZ Tiles layer, but is is not showing.
And I can not figure out what it is. What can I check to see what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I see a QGIS on Mac but which OSX version and more important, which QGIS version.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I suggest you check if you have the latest version of QGIS on your machine first. If not, please download the latest version and install it.

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages, as they are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others to locate your Q&A. Instead, copy the message text into the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me how to use Stack Overflow. I use the latest stable version of both OS and QGIS. But we can also close this question for now. Someone already helped me out with this.